# Testing if there is an entity with a objective score lower than another objective score

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Say there is a player called Dave with a Health score of 10 and a MaxHealth score of 20. I need to check if there is any players with a health score lower than MaxHealth and tellraw it. Also is there a way to add values onto Health say 60 or 20 but without it going over MaxHealth? E.G. Health + 60 = MaxHealth (without going over)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How can I tellraw all players with less than full health:**

You can use

```
/scoreboard players operation <targetName> <targetObjective> <operation> <selector> <objective>
```

to modify a players score by the value of another score(even between players).

But unfortunately, I couldn't find an objective criteria for MAX_HEALTH. (might be worth a feature request on [bugs.mojang.com](http://bugs.mojang.com))

If there should be one, you would need 3 objectives to do what you want:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Health health
/scoreboard objectives add MaxHealth maxHealth
/scoreboard objectives add HealthLost dummy
```

You need a clock to run all of these following commands:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players operation @p HealthLost = @p MaxHealth
execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players operation @p HealthLost -= @p Health
```

For the tellraw, use the selector tag in the json text:

```
/tellraw @a {text: "All these players are hurt: ",extra:[{selector:"@a[score_HealthLost_min=1]"}]}
```

**How can I heal players without going over maxHealth:**

You can't modify a health scoreboard value. Instead use the

```
/effect <player> <effect> [seconds] [amplifier] [hideParticles]
```

command to heal players. The amount of health added is equal to `duration * 2 ^ amplifier`

See [Potion effects](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect) (ID 6)

**Edit according to comment:**

(All objectives = dummy)
You can use the operation command again to achieve this:
Just add an arbitrary value to your score and then execute this:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players operation @p Health < @p MaxHealth
```

This will limit the "Health" score of every player to his "MaxHealth" score

Comment: Thanks but I actually didn't want to heal them. It was just need the bit that actually modifies the score. Health score should have a value added on but not going over the score set by MaxHealth. All values are dummy..